# PrintStream print does not have time to create a file

Tags: java, file, printstream

I have a method that create a file:

```
private void createFile(somedata) {
    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(
            new FileOutputStream(someData))) {
        out.print(Data);
               ...
}
```

And I need call this method 10 times in another method:

```
 createFile(somedata);
 ...
 createFile(somedata);
```

Problem:if i debug code - files are created, but if I just run code - only 1-3 files are created, not 10. I can not edit createFile()  method. Is there a way to fix this without using delay?

Comment: What is `somedata`?

Comment: someData - method that return string - path and randomly generated file name(depend from time).

Comment: Are you flushing?

Comment: When you call 10 times, is it called with 10 different `somedata` values

Comment: flush does not help.  data differ only in the file name. directory constant

Comment: You say that the file name is based on the time. If it's just a timestamp, is it possible that when running normally, it runs quickly enough that some iterations of the "loop" get the same timestamp, and thus re-write the same file?